# Is it possible ? I want to read the data from active directory and insert into sql server table using SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have a client requirement in that i need to read the data from active directory server and populate these data to sql server table using SSIS(Or any other approach)

I have

1.Active directory server name

2. AD login details
3. Powershell script which they used to pull the required fields manually .

I refer below post but its not working for me.

https://dataqueen.unlimitedviz.com/2012/05/importing-data-from-active-directory-using-ssis/

Thanks

Comment: What does "not working for me" mean? That's not a problem description or error message

Comment: Please ignore the last two lines.My problem is how to get data from active directory in to my sql table using ssis or any other approach.

Comment: Yes, that was in the title. What was the *problem*? Why didn't the article work? SSIS isn't broken.

Comment: Perhaps you could try this and get back with a specific description if you have any issues: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/PowerShell/137871/ No one is going to serve a complete solution up to you, particularly since whatever issue you are having now will likely stop any other approach.

Comment: Hello Friends,I mention the steps and error msg at below post.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/61bfdd18-7198-4f3d-b4ea-86fb9a5fc9ee/is-it-possible-i-want-to-read-the-data-from-active-directory-and-insert-into-sql-server-table?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.